# Mixed structure with int and string

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, c, string

I want to create a structure like this:

```
 struct commands
{
  int   cmd;
  char  descr[25];
};

commands cmds[] =
{
  {16, "Hammond Organ"},
  {17, "Percussive Organ"},
  {18, "Rock Organ"},
  { 0, "" }                   // end of list marker 
};
```

The compiler doesn't protest, but in a simulator the values of cmds[i].descr are all zeros.

And the line

```
Serial.write(cmds[1].descr);
```

prints nothing.

Please recommend how to rewrite the code.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot.

There is something wrong with the simulator (Simulator for Arduino - version 1.11E Designed by Virtronics). In the meantime I received the Mega 2560 board and the code works well with the board.

Comment: What version of the IDE and avr-g++ are you using? If you enable verbose compilation, you should see the location of the avr-tools (avr-g++, avr-objdump...) and the generated elf file. Run `avr-nm -Cn path_to_the_elf_file` to see the memory address where `cmds` is stored, then `avr-objdump -s -j .data path_to_the_elf_file` to see its contents. Does it look as expected?

Comment: Arduino IDE 1.8.10. As I am a beginner, I don't understand the rest of your question.

Comment: My issue is now resolved by the answers of VillageTech and VE7JRO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something wrong with the simulator you're using, because your code works for me (Arduino IDE 1.8.9, OSX, Arduino Uno).

```
struct commands
{
  int   cmd;
  char  descr[25];
};

commands cmds[] =
{
  {16, "Hammond Organ"},
  {17, "Percussive Organ"},
  {18, "Rock Organ"},
  { 0, "" }                   // end of list marker 
};

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.write(cmds[1].descr);
}

void loop(){}
```

Comment: The above sketch produces no errors or warnings using my OS and IDE version.

Comment: Same here. Compiles cleanly with `-Os -Wall -Wextra` and works perfectly with both avr-g++ 5.4.0 (shipped with Ubuntu 19.10) and 7.3.0 (shipped with the Arduino IDE 1.8.10).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use char pointer notation (char *) instead of array notation (char[]) in structure declaration:

```
struct commands
{
    int   cmd;
    char*  descr;
};
```

- OR -

use struct declaration as-is, but change the array initialization like below:

```
commands cmds[] =
{
    {16, {"Hammond Organ"}},
    {17, {"Percussive Organ"}},
    {18, {"Rock Organ"}},
    { 0, {""}}                   // end of list marker 
};
```

Additionally, it seems that it always should be written as:

```
struct commands cmds[] = 
{
    // here your code
};
```

If you have disabled warnings in your compiler, enable them again - and try to write program the way that you will newer receive warnings.

Thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot.

There must be something wrong with the simulator (Simulator for Arduino - version 1.11E Designed by Virtronics).
In the meantime I received the Mega 2560 board and both char pointer notation (char *) and array notation (char[]) work well with the board.
The compiler (Arduino IDE v. 1.8.10) really produces warnings: 
ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings].
Perhaps the simulator is more meticulous than the compiler and therefore refuses to work with a code thar generates warnings.